# Redirecting System.out.println to an AWT Component on button press

Tags: java

I have the following code and want to print the `System.out.println(result);` to my frame but I don't know how.  I tried `txtField.setText(result)` however this did not work.

I just want to display `System.out.println(result);` to that Form

```
 Public static void main(String...args) throws IOException {

            String line = null;
            Pattern category = Pattern.compile("^\\[(.*?)\\]$"); // matches [Cars]
            Pattern itemAndQuantity = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+)=(\\d+)$"); // matches Lamborghini=6
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/test.txt"))) {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    Matcher categoryMatcher = category.matcher(line);
                    Matcher itemMatcher = itemAndQuantity.matcher(line);
                    if (categoryMatcher.matches()) {
                        if (result.length() > 0) { // found new category, put on new line
                            result.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                        }
                        String categoryName = categoryMatcher.group(1); // Cars
                        result.append(categoryName).append(": "); // Cars: 
                    } else if (itemMatcher.matches()) {
                        String item = itemMatcher.group(1); // Lamborghini
                        String quantity = itemMatcher.group(2); // 6
                        result.append(item).append(" ") // Lamborghini
                              .append(quantity) // Lamborghini 6
                              .append(", "); // Lamborghini 6,
                    }
                }


                // we are done processing the file, output the result
                System.out.println(result);
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"? Are you getting an error or does the program not work as intended?

Comment: `txtField.setText(result)` should have a capital T in `setText`

Comment: when i add textField.settext(result). the code give's me errors one after one, and can't run the code!

Comment: @DanilGaponov already tried that it won't work. Any ideea? because i use stringbuidler (result) = new stringbuilder();

Comment: Well, then add the code where you have tried that and then keep in mind that `JTextField` does not support multiple lines. It will show them as one.

Comment: You need to use `txtField.setText(result.toString())` so that the `StringBuilder` can return the `String` stored in it.

Comment: @Tom just replaced the systemout.println(result); with textField.setText(result); and is not working. that's why i asked for help with this. ok then JTextPane but how

Comment: @TNT tried that to. Not working can`t run the code

Comment: And what kind of hidden error messages are there? Or are them not hidden you're just not showing them to us?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT EDIT:

The below answer was written when I was inexperienced and is only left for context. Disregard it and consider only the information provided in this edit edit.

What you have is a StringBuilder object with the text you want container within it. When you do `System.out.println(result)` it most likely calls the [StringBuilder#toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString--) method on `result` which extracts this text from the StringBuilder. Calling txtField.setText() most likely does not do this implicit conversion which is why it doesn't appear to work.

What you want to do is call `txtField.setText(result.toString())` to get the text contained in the StringBuilder and set the text field's text to that.

See:

- [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)
- [Using Swing Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

---

EDIT:

Replace the System.out.println with the following:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JTextField text;
text = new JTextField(result.toString());
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

---

<s>Firstly, I cannot tell if you've imported all necessary packages, if you haven't that is most likely your first error.</s>

```
public static void main(String...args)
```

<s>not</s>

```
public static void main(String...args)
```

<s>Also, I'd recommend adding the following code after your try whenever you create a try statement:</s>

```
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("An exception occurred");
}
```

<s>You can add anything instead of System.out.println("An exception occurred") but that's the simplest I can think of to notify you that an error occurred.</s>

Comment: yes i did imported all necessary packages. I don`t know if u guys have tried the info's u gave me but for me are not working

Comment: @clopotziel I was just trying to fix the error, as for redirecting the text I am still trying to figure that out. "public" instead of "Public" is pretty important.

Comment: @clopotziel You want the string to appear in the text file, correct? Because I can help you to add it to a window.

Comment: i know what u mean, i just copied the code from eclipse and copied without "p" so i added it , my bad for a big PxD

Comment: @clopotziel what does the test.txt file contain?

Comment: it contains 3 lines:
[Cars]
bmw=3
Lamborghini=10

Comment: @clopotziel What is the output you expect?

Comment: `[Cars]
Bmw=1  
Lamborghini=10`

`[CARS] == is the category
BMW, Lamborghini = Descriptor
1,5,3 = Values`

`Output: [Category]
descriptor1  3 pieces
descriptor2  10 pieces`

Remember that the txt file is changed by another program that inserts lines like that

Just run the code i show and modify the lines , or add another ones ..

Comment: @clopotziel What I posted in the edit ran for me just fine so it should work for you unless the "program" you use affect it which I doubt it would.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you've given to us so far, there are several things wrong:

```
Public static void main(String...args) throws IOException {
```

The P here should be lowercase. Also you should wrap code that may throw an `IOException` in a try-catch statement instead of using `throws IOException`; it's good coding practice to do so, since an `IOException` that may occur will be left unhandled...

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/test.txt"))) {
```

You're missing your `catch` statement at the end of the `try`...

```
txtField.settext(result)
```

It shoud be `txtField.setText(result.toString())`. Note that the T is capitalized and `toString()` returns the `String` stored in the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: If i run the code with system.outprintln(result); Everything works fine. If i change it to txtField.setText(result.toString()) nothing wrongs

Comment: Sockel: nio 1, io 10, 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at nioCounter.Vlad.main(Vlad.java:57)

          got textField.setText(result.toString()); at line 57